# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object to GenericList

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net

I have recently finished writing up a proof of concept on a rather extensive REST API to support our legacy data components. However I've found that it's been running quite slowly when processing larger data sets (40k+ items).

After some researching I found a thread on SO claiming that it could be more efficient by using `memorystream`, `HttpClientHandlers` and more importantly compression in terms of `Gzip`. So I updated my current .NET version and started to rewrite the API in VS2017.

***(It should be mentioned that I've never worked with these datastructures)***

I then followed along in the example, but have hit a wall. I'm getting this error message when attempting to get some data out of the API (**this is just a snippet of the error**):

> "Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Cannot
>   deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into
>   type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RESTWebApi.Models.TRK_TrackerFeatures]'

And this is the code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAll()
{
    DataSet ds = dc.FETCHTRK_TrackerFeatures("", conStr, "");
    List<TRK_TrackerFeatures> arr = new List<TRK_TrackerFeatures>();
    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            int? id = row["ID"] as int?;
            String trackercode = row["TrackerCode"] as String;
            Boolean? applicabletoproject = row["ApplicableToProject"] as Boolean?;
            int? trk_feature_lkid = row["TRK_Feature_LKID"] as int?;
            int? trk_trackerstatus_lkid = row["TRK_TrackerStatus_LKID"] as int?;
            int? trk_trackerstatus_lkid2 = row["TRK_TrackerStatus_LKID2"] as int?;
            Boolean? readyforwork = row["ReadyForWork"] as Boolean?;
            String action = row["Action"] as String;
            String responsibleperson = row["ResponsiblePerson"] as String;
            int? tminus = row["TMinus"] as int?;
            DateTime? datetobeactioned = row["DateToBeActioned"] as DateTime?;
            int? trk_startdateid = row["TRK_StartDateID"] as int?;
            String accountableperson = row["AccountablePerson"] as String;
            String comments = row["Comments"] as String;
            DateTime? datestamp = row["DateStamp"] as DateTime?;
            arr.Add(new TRK_TrackerFeatures
            {
                ID = id,
                TrackerCode = trackercode,
                ApplicableToProject = applicabletoproject,
                TRK_Feature_LKID = trk_feature_lkid,
                TRK_TrackerStatus_LKID = trk_trackerstatus_lkid,
                TRK_TrackerStatus_LKID2 = trk_trackerstatus_lkid2,
                ReadyForWork = readyforwork,
                Action = action,
                ResponsiblePerson = responsibleperson,
                TMinus = tminus,
                DateToBeActioned = datetobeactioned,
                TRK_StartDateID = trk_startdateid,
                AccountablePerson = accountableperson,
                Comments = comments,
                DateStamp = datestamp
            });
        }
    }
    using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler, false))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr);
            byte[] jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                gzip.Write(jsonBytes, 0, jsonBytes.Length);
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            StreamContent content = new StreamContent(ms);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:61090/api/TRK_TrackerFeatures/GetAll", content);
            List<TRK_TrackerFeatures> results = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<TRK_TrackerFeatures>>(); <== error here
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", results)); // 
        }
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: ReadAsAsync<T> is definitely some extension. What exactly is it? Could you show what it the response you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: If I remember correctly from working with Xamarin it's a method that reads the (in this case) content of a response asynchronously. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontentextensions.readasasync(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: sorry I didn't find that it is Xamarin. Anyway more likely the problem is in a way you deserialize response data. Could you provide a result of `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` ?

Comment: That's not correct syntax. `Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` requires an object like my syntax provides. Clearly it has to do with the deserialization as that's what the error mentions. :)

Comment: You can deserialize that list with Json.Net but to use Content.ReadAsAsync you have to tell the content deserializer to use Json.Net, or read the string and than use Json.Net

Comment: First you need to do is to get string response content. Then you can understand why received json does not fit your model. Base on the error you have json object instead of json array.

Comment: @IvanChepikov I guess the json does fit the model, but the deserializer (used by ReadAsAsync) cannot handle it

Comment: @SirRufo I know. but base on 'http://localhost:61090' I can say that both server and client are developed by the author. And it is more likely a logic then serialization problem. When we see Json response more likely we will decide to change the model. It is just my guess but anyway it will be useful to see the response string.

Comment: @IvanChepikov Agree, seeing the response will move us from religion to facts ;o)

Comment: In all honesty I can't get any data out of even GET requests. I just changed the results to `Content.ReadAsStringAsync` to see if I can grab the data like that. But now I'm getting a `Method does not support action POST`, even though I'm sending PostMan GET-requests...

It should be mentioned that the data works absolutely fine when not using `HttpClientHandler` and streams. As can be seen here: 
http://api.worksiteclouddev.com/RestfulAPI/api/TRK_TrackerFeatures/GetAll

Comment: Oh yes, it is working like a charm => **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 24982 column 16 of the JSON data**

Comment: huh? I'm not getting any such errors. I'm running Chrome and have checked both Network and for errors in the Console.

Comment: @geostocker me neither. json from [here](http://api.worksiteclouddev.com/RestfulAPI/api/TRK_TrackerFeatures/GetAll) is fine. It mean that Post is not the same. Is there a chance that HttpClient doesn't make unzip automatically? I have heard something like this in WinPhone 8.0 if I remember right.

Comment: Are you sure you want to **POST** something to the API method `GetAll`? I just made a simple **GET** request to that API method and all results were deserialized fine to a typed list `var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<TrackerFeature>>();`

Comment: No, you are misunderstanding! For some reason a GET-request is interpreted as a POST by the VS2017 service (but correctly on the live version). 

So when I check what `results` is after `var results = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` I get that error message. Again, this is on the VS2017 version, not on the live version. On live everything is running as intended (slow, though!).

Comment: Ehhm, your code: `client.PostAsync("http://localhost:61090/api/TRK_TrackerFeatures/GetAll", content)`

Comment: LOOOOL OMFG.....

Comment: God, do I feel stupid now. Completely messed up there...

Solved it by returning a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`.

However I've seen a decline in speed using this solution. The live version gives me a response within 17 seconds and the localhost version takes about 30 seconds. Do you have any other proposed solutions to handling this amount of items?